# Should an adverb which modifies “be” be omitted when “which is” omitted?

Tags: implication

Should an adverb which modifies “be” be omitted when “which is” omitted?

For example, “an apple which is red universally.”

If I omit “which is” (an apple red universally), should I omit “universally”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an attempt at [whiz-deletion](http://wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=24650#:%7E:text=The%20rule%20called%20Whiz%2DDeletion,is%20left%20after%20the%20deletion.)- removal of **which is** from a sentence. There is a rule that says that you can't do whiz-deletion if what's left is just an adjective: if this happens, you must move the adjective to its normal position before the noun.

> An apple which is red - *complete phrase- correct*
> An apple red - *whiz-deletion phrase- **incorrect***
> A red apple - *modified whiz-deletion phrase- correct*

There is an additional problem: it's not at all clear what **universally** is supposed to mean in this context.

If you replace **universally** with an adverbial phrase **all over** (meaning that all parts of the apple are red) or **in places** (meaning that only some parts of the apple are red), you get something that is meaningful, and whiz-deletion can be used because you no longer have a single adjective:

> An apple which is red all over
> An apple red all over

This is just an example to show how it works: a native speaker would be more likely to say "a completely red apple". A more realistic example to work on would be

> a person who is devoid of humanity

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to say something. Should I omit also auxiliaries? Ex. an apple which will be red all over > an apple red all over?

Comment: No, whiz-deletion lets you delete a wh-word and a be-word, and the be-word has to be present tense.

Comment: “Be” is okay even though it’s an auxiliary?

Comment: **be** can be both an auxiliary verb "I am working" and a main verb "I am busy". Whiz deletion only works with be, and only works when it's the main verb..

Comment: @JavaLatte I don't agree with your comment. "Be" always qualifies as an auxiliary verb, even when it's the only verb in the clause taking a complement with the form of an AdjP, NP etc. Note that in inversion and negation it requires _n't_ or "not" (“He isn’t busy") while lexical verbs require _do_ support (“He doesn’t take the money”, not *”He takes not the money”)